# NextJS: loading json into getInitialProps in _app.js vs pages and avoiding double calling

Tags: reactjs, redux, next.js

I've used getInitialProps to load a large json file onto an individual page. Since it's a rather large json, I was wondering how I should go about loading it onto the index page to start with. The subpages should load it only if someone goes onto a subpage directly bypassing the index and it's not in the props already. The docs are a bit confusing on loading onto the _app compared to individual components. Also, not clear how to do a check within then getInitialProps if the props are already fetched...

```
import App from 'next/app'
import React from 'react'
import withReduxStore from '../store/with-redux-store'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import "isomorphic-fetch"

class MyApp extends App {
  static async getInitialProps({ Component, ctx }) {
    let res = await fetch('https://xxxx.json', { mode: 'no-cors' });
    let productParams = await res.text().then((data) => {
      return (data ? JSON.parse(data) : {})
    })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error("Something bad happened", error);
      });
    console.log(`Show data fetched. Count: ${Object.keys(productParams).length}`);
    return { productParams, topState: "loaded" }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={reduxStore}>
        <Component {...this.props} />
      </Provider>
    )
  }
}

export default withReduxStore(MyApp)


________________________________________________


class SubPage extends React.Component {

  static async getInitialProps({ reduxStore, topState }) {
    reduxStore.dispatch(loadInitialState());

    if (topState != "loaded") {
      let res = await fetch('https://xxxxxx.json', { mode: 'no-cors' })
      let productParams = await res.json();
      return { productParams }
     } else {
    return {}
     }
  }
  state = { ...this.props, riskType: "xxx" }

  componentDidMount() {
    console.log(this.state);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Layout>
       <SubComponent />
      </Layout>

    )
  }
}


const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return state;
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    loadInitialState: () => {
      dispatch({ type: "LOAD_INITIAL_STATE" });
    }
  };
};



export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(SubPage)
```

If I go to the main page, the _app loads the json, then if I click on the subpage link, its no longer in the props. Only when I reload the subpage, it appears in the props again. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

From what I can gather, your example seems to have several issues. But the main ones that would need addressing for your scenario to work are:

1. `Component` on `_app.js` is actually a prop passed to your `MyApp` component.
2. Since you are overriding it, you should call `App.getInitialProps` inside your static `MyApp.getInitialProps`. That would actually trigger calls to your page's own `getInitialProps`.
3. The props returned from `getInitialProps` in `_app.js` are sent as `pageProps` to `MyApp`.

Putting it all together would look something like this:

```js
import App from 'next/app'

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return <Component {...pageProps} />
}

MyApp.getInitialProps = async (appContext) => {
   // calls page's `getInitialProps` and fills `appProps.pageProps`
   const appProps = await App.getInitialProps(appContext);

   // Fetch your json file
   const res = await fetch('https://xxxx.json', { mode: 'no-cors' });
   const productParams = await res.json();

   return { ...appProps, productParams, topState: "loaded" };
 }

export default MyApp
```

Just bear in mind that setting a `getInitialProps` from your custom `App` will force every page on your app to be server side rendered and void static optimization, entirely.  You can read more about custom `App` on its [official documentation section](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-app).